# Dynamically specify WCF Service endpoint by environment variable

Tags: wcf, mvvm, configuration

I am working to create a MVVM client app that uses a WCF service to perform CRUD operations in a database. I also have 4 deployment environments that use the same service, but located on 4 different servers.
so here is some Pseudo-Code to explain better:

In the App.Config:

```
 <appSettings>
<add key="Local.Server.Service" value="Local.Service" />
<add key="Development.Server.Service" value="Development.Service" />
<add key="Test.Server.Service" value="Test.Service" />
<add key="Pre-Prod.Server.Service" value="Pre-Prod.Service" />
<add key="Production.Server.Service" value="Production.Service" />

</appSettings>
   <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
   maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
    maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
     <service name="Local.Service">
        <endpoint address="Local.address" 
  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"/>
     </service>
     <service name="Dev.Service">
        <endpoint address="Dev.address" 
  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"/>
     </service>
     <service name="Test.Service">
        <endpoint address="Test.address" 
bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"/>
     </service>
     <service name="Prod.Service">
        <endpoint address="Prod.address" 
bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"/>
     </service>

    </services>
```

In the VM:

```
  private const string ENV_VARIABLE = "Test";
  public string GetServiceUri()
  {
       var uri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(string.Concat(ENV_VARIABLE, ".Server.Service"));
       return uri;   
  }
```

From here I can call the GetServiceUri to the name of the service, but I cannot figure out how to get the endpoint address for the service.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i ended up changing the app.config file to include the different endpoints in a single client, instead of individual services, and tweaking the binding configuration, as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="Local.address"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
    contract="ServiceReference.IService"
    name="Local.BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
  <endpoint address="Dev.address"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
    contract="ServiceReference.IService"
    name="Dev.BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
  <endpoint address="Test.address"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
    contract="ServiceReference.IService"
    name="Test.BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
  <endpoint address="Prod.address"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
    contract="ServiceReference.IService"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```